# How to force javascript Array to inherit from my custom object?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Is it possible to do something like this - force standard javascript object inherit from custom object? (no practical use, just rhetorical question).

```
var MyObject=function(){
        this.name="name from MyObject";
      }

Array.prototype=new MyObject();
var array = new Array();
console.log(array.name); //undefined
```

Comment: You can't. Why not just add properties to `Array.prototype`? It would have basically the same effect.

Comment: @squint: It's generally considered a bad idea to extend built-in objects in JavaScript, is it not? Granted, this idea is worse by orders of magnitude.

Comment: You could just have a look at the [spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.3.1) to find out that `Array.prototype` is not writable. So, theoretically it's possible, but you have to check the configuration of the property first.

Comment: Felix Kling: While that's true in ECMAScript 5, it was not, necessarily true in ECMAScript 3, which is (sadly) still installed on a large number of machines.

Comment: @MikeHofer: No, the best practice is to define an overall strategy that works together sensibly as a unit. This may involve extending native prototypes, or may not. What's a bad practice is to have various strategies that when used together, produce bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, you can reassign the prototype of the Array. But doing so would likely have horrific consequences.

ECMAScript (upon which JavaScript is based) makes certain fundamental assumptions about arrays. I would imagine that some implementations of ECMAScript would prohibit the reassignment of the prototype of an intrinsic class, while others would allow it (since an equally fundamental rule of JavaScript is that anything can be changed anywhere at any time).

Doing this, however, would render the Array completely unpredictable and unreliable.

Comment: I am asking not because I want to change Array, I am reading again abt inheritance and it is just rhetorical question.. I assume any object in javascript can change parent, right?

Comment: In earlier versions of ECMAScript, yes. As of ES 5, this is no longer true.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because modification of this property is disabled (I think it is a requirement of ECMAScript 5 specification for native objects, but couldn't find anything to prove it). In chrome running this query:

```
     Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Array, 'prototype')
```

shows the descriptor of the property

```
     Object {
       value: Array[0], 
       writable: false, 
       enumerable: false,
       configurable: false
     }
```